# how to query with polymorphic has_one association's attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using polymorphic association to argument my `Post` model (which has common post attributes-title, body, date, etc... )

Here's my models,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_module, polymorphic: true
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post, as: :post_module
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end
```

Now I have a `Post` model which has an `Album` model as `:post_module`

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id]) #its :post_module is an Album model
```

Now I want to query `Post`s which has an Album model with same artist id of that post's album's artist id.

I can query `Album` models with same artist id of that `@post`'s album... but That's not what I want..

I want a set of `Post`

```
@albums = Album.where('albums.artist_id = "?"', @post.post_module.artist.id)
```

How can I do this? or am I designing a bad model relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with

`Post.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN albums ON albums.id = posts.post_module_id').where('posts.post_module_type = "Album" AND albums.artist_id = "?"', @artist.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Posts for an artist

```
artist = Artist.last

#This will get a scoped object for all posts belonging to this artist's albums
posts = Post.where(id: artist.albums)
```

For your model design, two suggestions:

1. If only Album will associate with Post, no need polymorphic, though I guess you may have more.
2. For polymorphic name, a convention is to use adj, `postable` instead of `post_module`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve all the posts for a given artist id. So:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:post_module => :album).where(:post_module => { :album => { :artist_id => artist_id }})
```

Comment: it don't work with error with NameError: uninitialized constant Post::PostModule